# Which big O represents better worst running time?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, computer-science

I am looking at this question:

> Which of the following time complexities represent better worst running time?
>
> (a) O(lg(n!))
> (b) O(n)
> (c) O(n²)
> (d) O(lg(lg(n)))
> (e) none of the above
>
> **Answer:** (d)

According to options, option d should be the *best* case because it takes the least time.

And option c should be the *worst* case, according to options.

Why the answer is option (d) if the question is about the worst case?

Comment: It's not asking about the _worst_ running time, but about the _best_ worst-case running time.

Comment: Will you please elaborate

Comment: Is there some lead-up to that question? Option (e) suggests that this might be w.r.t. some algorithm, otherwise "none" makes no sense (one has to be the best).

Comment: What is the difference between worst running time and better worst running time

Comment: Again, it's not asking for "worst running time" but "worst _case_ running time". As a simple example, consider inserting into an array. If you insert near the last position, running time will be close to O(1), but if you insert at the front of the array, so that all elements have to be shifted, running time is O(n). This is the "worst case running time".

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm X can take anywhere between 1 second and 10 seconds. Algorithm Y can take anywhere between 5 seconds and 6 seconds. Which algorithm has better running time, X or Y?

It depends what exact characteristic of the algorithms you are comparing. There are several to consider. Among those are the *best case running time*, the *worst case running time*, and the *average case running time*.

If comparing the *best case running time*, X is better than Y, because *the best time of X* is smaller than *the best time of Y*.

If comparing the *worst case running time*, Y is better than X, because *the worst time of Y* is smaller than *the worst time of X*.

If comparing the *average case running time* ... that's the control question! What is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the **limiting** behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity. [...] A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only provides an **upper bound** on the growth rate of the function.

Let's say we have a function  that has a big O description of O(²), then that function *might* still behave much better in the best case, and in that case be described with -- let's say -- O().

Worst and best case are only relevant concepts when there are aspects of the input that can vary, even when  remains the same. A typical example is a sort function. In that case we take  to be the *size* of the array to be sorted, but the actual values in that array can still vary. Sometimes those values give us a best case, sometimes a worst case, sometimes something in between...

If all we have is that big O notation, we cannot exclude there is a *worst* case for that function, where it really meets that asymptotic limit.

Now in that list of options we see what the *worst* case asymptotic behaviour of those functions would be, and from those we should pick the **better** one.